# Pandas - Styling a data frame with mixed type columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-styles

**Hello friends,
I would like to apply a styling function on a data frame that contains numeric and non numeric column types.
How can I avoid the error below?**

---

**Error:**
TypeError: ("'>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'", 'occurred at index A')

---

[image]

---

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'A': ['A','B','C']}
data = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
data['B']=[7,8,9]
data['C']=[1,2,3]

def color_negative_red(val):
    """
    Takes a scalar and returns a string with
    the css property `'color: red'` for negative
    strings, black otherwise.
    """
    color = 'white' if (val > 2) else 'black'
    return 'color: %s' % color

df_new = data.style.applymap(color_negative_red)
```

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea if more complicated data is create custom function - here are selected only numeric columns with [`DataFrame.select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html), set output `df1` to empty strings and replace numeric values by [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
def color_negative_red(x):
    c1 = 'background-color: red'
    c2 = 'background-color: black' 

    cols = x.select_dtypes(np.number).columns
    df1 = pd.DataFrame('', index=x.index, columns=x.columns)
    df1[cols] = np.where(x[cols] > 2, c1, c2)
    return df1

df.style.apply(color_negative_red, axis=None)
```